# web form not being submitted in IE 11 but is submitted using IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have a serious issue with my code/browser. 
I tried to implement solution provided here at SO, but none is working from me.
here are some of the one I looked:

1. [jQuery's $(form).submit() not firing for IE only (MVC3 app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201278/jquerys-form-submit-not-firing-for-ie-only-mvc3-app)
2. [jQuery: form not submitting with $("#id").submit(), but will submit with a 'submit' button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303874/jquery-form-not-submitting-with-id-submit-but-will-submit-with-a-subm)
3. [Form Submit jQuery does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982741/form-submit-jquery-does-not-work)

My issue is: I have a submit button that is not working on IE11 but when I downgrade the version IE8 using IE Developer Tools it works fine. Any clue? I have half my hair already pulled out since it's been 3 days I am trying to get it work on IE 11. Any idea is welcome.

This is the jquery code:

```
if (isOtherValid == true) {
                    formsubmit = true;
                    $('#StupidForm').submit();

                    document.StupidForm.submit()
                    alert('Test');




                    form.submit();
                    return true;

                }
            }
            else {
                alert('You must select at least 1 CE type');
            }
```

This is my razor view:

```
 @model TCEO.MVC.Person.MyModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Course Sign Up";
    }


    @section Styles {
        <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/enroll_learner_validation.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <h2>@Model.courseEnrollment.CourseTitle</h2>

    <div style="padding-left:25px;">
        @{
            var namePrint = Model.FirstName;
            if (!(Model.MiddleInitial == null) && Model.MiddleInitial.Length == 1)
            { namePrint = namePrint + " " + Model.MiddleInitial + ". "; }
            else
            { namePrint = namePrint + " "; }
            namePrint = namePrint + Model.LastName;
            <span style=" font-size:18px; color:navy;">@namePrint</span>
            <br /><br />

        }

        <h3>Update Your Account</h3>
        <span style=" font-size:18px; color:navy;">Verify your information below...</span>

        @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }

        @using (Html.BeginForm("EnrollLearnerValidationCompleteForm", "Course", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "StupidForm" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
            <legend></legend>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LearnerID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MiddleInitial)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressLine1)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressLine2)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressLine3)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.City)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CountrySelectedItem)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StateSelectedItem)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ZipCode)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.courseEnrollment.AdjustRecord)


            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)   
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Any code you are using???

Comment: some code would be nice